# How to set the home execution dir of tomcat application server?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat8

`tomcat8` can be installed on `ubuntu` using either `apt-get install tomcat8`, or downloading the `tar.gz` archive and extract it manually.

Problem: the root execution path seems to differ between the installed and the extracted one. I'd like to know how the root path is set for the installed one?

`catalina.out` shows:

- apt-get installed tomcat:
  `... PID 1234 (started by tomcat8 in /var/lib/tomcat8)`
- simple extracted tar.gz tomcat archive installation:
  `... PID 1234 (started by tomcat8 in /)`

Question: why does the "manually" extracted tomcat have a different home directory `/` than the apt-get installed one `/var/lib/tomcat8`?
Where is this path configured?

Sidenote: it clearing doesn't come from cataline-paths: both tomcats show the correct environment variables:

This is there apt-get installes the home dir by default:

```
CATALINA_BASE: /usr/share/tomcat8
CATALINA_HOME: /usr/share/tomcat8
```

extracted:

```
CATALINA_BASE: /opt/tomcat
CATALINA_HOME: /opt/tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service`

Add the following line:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat
```